# Add fields to Worfklow status page Tasks section

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

How do you add fields to the Tasks section of a workflow status page for SharePoint online? I'm using a 2013 Workflow.

[image]

I would like to add/remove columns from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add/remove a column on the Tasks section of workflow status page, you need to change wrkstat.aspx page which is a file from server side. However, as you know, in SharePoint Online, we are unable to access server side which is controlled by Microsoft. So, currently, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I will just have to live without.